# rickshaw graph x,y pair with y to be string

Tags: graph, rickshaw

I am using rickshaw graph to visualize my time series.

In the tutorial, we need data pair (x, y),  where y has to be type double or int to plot like:

```
var data = [ { x: -1893456000, y: 92228531 }, { x: -1577923200, y: 106021568 }, { x: -1262304000, y: 123202660 } ];
```

is there anyway I can put string at y, like

```
var data = [ { x: -1893456000, y: "ID12" }, { x: -1577923200, y: "ID10" }, { x: -1262304000, y: "ID8" } ];
```

because I want to use the example http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/hover.html

to show the timeseries of IDs when mouse over.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it works this way. But what you can do is, use a numeric Y value (eg 12 for ID12) and use a yFormatter in your hoverDetail:

```
var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({graph: graph,
    xFormatter: function(x) {return x},
    yFormatter: function(y) {return "ID"+y}
});
```

I think this should do the Trick